# $_SESSION problem - I have same ID on all <tr>

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, tr

I don’t know, how I do this: I want to add `$id` from database to `$_SESSION["dbID"]` and after click, it shows me more information from database. But table generates in while function and `$_SESSION["dbID"]` every time set to the highest number of row from table. Please, Can you anyone change my code as I have `$_SESSION["dbID"]` on every `<tr>` of table different? Thank you

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
   $id=$row['ID'];
   $name=$row['Name'];
   $subject=$row['Subject'];
   $date=$row['Date'];

   echo 
       '<tr class="trX" id="'.$id.'" href="google.com&id='.$row['ID'].'">
           <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php">' . $id . '</a></td>
           <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php">' . $name . '</td>
           <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php">' . $subject . '</td>
           <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php">' . $date . '</td>
       </tr>';
 
}
$_SESSION["dbID"] = $id;
echo ' </table>  ';
```

Comment: You don't want SESSION for this, you want to add the `id` to the link

Comment: But why do you have multiple links in each row? and a `href` attribute in the tr?

Comment: Ou, I only test, if can I add href to tr, after this, I don’t have to add href to all td. But it isn’t work. And with JS Query, too. Do you know solution?

Comment: I suggest a little JS magic

Comment: Okay. It is solved. But I don’t know, how I get different $id on every row. Do you know how, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

You can do away with all of the `a` tags and use JavaScript to handle the redirect...

```
$url = "/path/to/file.php?id=" . $id;
```

Set the URL to the page that you want to link to. The line above shows the link to the file "file.php" on the server with the query string "id=$id".

```
onclick="window.location.href='...'"
```

The line above is a JS equivalent of `href`. If you want to navigate to a server outside of your domain remember to add the full url e.g. https://www.website.com

### Code example

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $id      = $row['ID'];
   $name    = $row['Name'];
   $subject = $row['Subject'];
   $date    = $row['Date'];

   $url     = "/url/path.php?id=" . $id;

   echo <<<EOT
       <tr class="trX" onclick="window.location.href='{$url}'">
           <td class="tdX">{$id}</td>
           <td class="tdX">{$name}</td>
           <td class="tdX">{$subject}</td>
           <td class="tdX">{$date}</td>
       </tr>
EOT;
}
echo ' </table>  ';
```

Comment: Yes. But $id is still max number of ids. How I do that, I want to different $id on every row, not the same...?

Comment: This would give you a different ID on each row. You no longer use SESSION instead you use GET

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>

    <tr class="trX" id="'.<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>.'" href="google.com&id='.$row['ID'].'">
        <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></a></td>
        <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
        <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php"><?php echo $row['Subject']; ?></td>
        <td class="tdX"><a style="color:black; text-decoration: none;" href="page.php"><?php echo $row['Date']; ?> </td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Dont define the rows just make a call for them in the databse.

Comment: This solution not works. It shows me anything, if tr isn’t in php. I don’t know why.

Comment: @MartanKing try the updated solution and see if it works

Comment: I used other solution from @Steven, but thank you :)